# Pass an object into an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a dynamically created object into an array in JavaScript. The object passes but when I try to retrieve the data inside the object, it is gone. The console logs 
round[object, object]. how can I make this work?

Here's my code:

```
function roundList(myRounds){

var savedRounds = [];
savedRounds.push(myRounds);
console.log("this is savedRounds " + savedRounds);
};

function round(course,tee,slope,rating,score){
this.course=course;
this.tee=tee;
this.slope=slope; 
this.rating=rating;         
this.score=score;   
}

function makeRound(){
var newCourse = document.getElementById('course').value
var newTee = document.getElementById('tee').value
var newSlope = document.getElementById('slope').value
var newRating = document.getElementById('rating').value
var newScore = document.getElementById('score').value
var newDate = document.getElementById('date').value
var newRound = new round(newCourse,newTee,newSlope,newRating,newScore);
    roundList(newRound);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear where you're trying to access the object, but the `var` in `var savedRounds = [];` means savedRounds is only locally scoped and only accessible inside `roundList` method.

If you want to access savedRounds outside the roundList method, then declare `savedRounds = [];` outside the `roundList` method or return it from the method so something else can access it.

Comment: ... and it means that when "roundList" returns, the array is gone.

Answer (score 1):

use `console.log(JSON.stringify(savedRounds))` instead

That will show you the full contents of the object.

As others have pointed out, you also are not persisting the object right now, and it will not be accessible after the function completes.

Comment: In Chrome, you can also use `console.log("Lorem Ipsum", object)` and still get a nice expandable log entry. As long as you use comas instead of concating everything into a string.